# Finding last "Non-Null" value in a Pivot query

Tags: php, sql-server, performance, pivot

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT * FROM 
                (
                    SELECT unix_timestamp, input_raw, tag_id 
                    from [200030].[dbo].inputs
                    WHERE inputs.date_time > dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
                    AND
                    (tag_id = 92164 or tag_id = 92149)
                ) src
                pivot
                (
                    max(input_raw)
                    FOR tag_id IN ([92164], [92149])
                ) piv
                ORDER by unix_timestamp DESC
```

which is great and works.  It gives me the results:

[image]

However, I would like the query to do one more thing for me.

Whenever there is a 'NULL' result, I would like the query to replace the 'NULL' with the last 'non-NULL' value in the column.

For example, the first NULL seen in column '92164' would be replaced with '211'.

Also, it is possible that there will be several 'NULL's i a row, so the query would need to keep going up the column until it finds a none NULL.

I have been able to accomplish this with php.  Putting the results into a 2D associative array and running a function that finds nulls then loops through to find the last non NULL, but I really want to do this all in SQL if possible. I'd much rather use the

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
  //code     
}
```

method than assigning several arrays.

Any help?

Thank you

//EDIT

Forgot to add that this only applies if there is any non-nulls above the null value.  For example it is acceptable if the first row is NULL.

Comment: Help me understand, if column 92164 is row 3 were null, you would want it to display 207? And you want column 92164 of row 5 to display 211?

Comment: @supergrady You are understanding the question correctly... and if rows 1-4 were all Nulls then they and row 5 would stay Null and row 7 would be 211.

Comment: @Love2Learn you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your pivot query in a CTE and reuse the CTE when you figure out what value to show. You data have null values only in the first column but here is a version that deals with the nulls in both columns.

```
WITH C AS
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
       SELECT unix_timestamp, input_raw, tag_id 
       FROM inputs
       WHERE date_time > dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) AND
             (tag_id = 92164 OR tag_id = 92149)
       ) src
  PIVOT
       (
       MAX(input_raw)
       FOR tag_id IN ([92164], [92149])
       ) piv
)
SELECT C1.unix_timestamp,
       (
       SELECT TOP(1) C2.[92164] 
       FROM C AS C2
       WHERE C1.unix_timestamp <= C2.unix_timestamp AND
             C2.[92164] IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY C2.unix_timestamp
       ) AS [92164],
       (
       SELECT TOP(1) C2.[92149] 
       FROM C AS C2
       WHERE C1.unix_timestamp <= C2.unix_timestamp AND
             C2.[92149] IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY C2.unix_timestamp
       ) AS [92149] 
FROM C AS C1
ORDER by C1.unix_timestamp DESC;
```

If you have a performance problem it might be faster for you to store the result from the CTE in a temp table with a useful clustered key index.

```
CREATE TABLE #C
(
  unix_timestamp int PRIMARY KEY,
  [92164] int,
  [92149] int
);

INSERT INTO #C
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT unix_timestamp, input_raw, tag_id 
      FROM inputs
      WHERE date_time > dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) AND
            (tag_id = 92164 OR tag_id = 92149)
      ) src
PIVOT
      (
      MAX(input_raw)
      FOR tag_id IN ([92164], [92149])
      ) piv;

SELECT C1.unix_timestamp,
       (
       SELECT TOP(1) C2.[92164] 
       FROM #C AS C2
       WHERE C1.unix_timestamp <= C2.unix_timestamp AND
             C2.[92164] IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY C2.unix_timestamp
       ) AS [92164],
       (
       SELECT TOP(1) C2.[92149] 
       FROM #C AS C2
       WHERE C1.unix_timestamp <= C2.unix_timestamp AND
             C2.[92149] IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY C2.unix_timestamp
       ) AS [92149]
FROM #C AS C1
ORDER by C1.unix_timestamp DESC;

DROP TABLE #C;
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with CTE.  I have tried to run this query using Microsoft SQL Management Studio and the query never seems to stop executing.

Comment: @Mildfire Added a second version that should have better performance. You have to test on your data.

Comment: Seems to be working.  Thank you very much.  The whole purpose of this is to be able to create a CSV string to use in dygraph.  You wouldnt happen to know of any good reading/tutorial material on the web for CTE would you.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Mildfire Have a look here. [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an adaptation of the "running total" calculation method [detailed here](http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/28/calculating-running-totals-in-sql-server-2005---the-optimal.aspx). Create a temp table or table variable to hold the results of your pivot query, with an extra column to hold the last not-null value of the 92164 column. I can't get SQLFiddle to do this, *but it works on my machine* (famous last words)

```
CREATE TABLE #pivot_results ([unix_timestamp] int, [92164] int, [92149] int)
INSERT INTO #pivot_results  ([unix_timestamp], [92164], [92149])
VALUES
    (1361893407, NULL, 294),
    (1361893218, 207, 294),
    (1361893108, NULL, 292),
    (1361892807, 211, 292),
    (1361892799, NULL, 292)    
CREATE TABLE #update_me 
    ([unix_timestamp] int, [92164] int, [92149] int, last_not_null_92164 int)

DECLARE @last_not_null_92164 INT = NULL;

INSERT INTO #update_me([unix_timestamp], [92164], [92149], last_not_null_92164)
SELECT unix_timestamp, [92164], [92149], NULL
FROM #pivot_results
ORDER BY unix_timestamp DESC

UPDATE #update_me
SET @last_not_null_92164 = last_not_null_92164 = ISNULL([92164],@last_not_null_92164)
FROM #update_me

SELECT 
     unix_timestamp
    ,last_not_null_92164 AS [92164]
    ,[92149] 
FROM #update_me
ORDER BY unix_timestamp DESC
```